# Custom PermissionEvaluator for authorizing resource access for each REST Resource

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, acl

I have implemented a REST application with some complicated authorization requirements.

Here's a summary

My customers purchase a proxy device called Collector that enables their home automation control to be centralized. My customers also purchase multiple home automation devices (let's call them HADevices) that report their metrics through the collector to my REST application.

An admin(who is my customer service rep), with role ROLE_ADMIN, should be able to look at any data from any Collector or HADevice. A customer, with role ROLE_USER role, should only be able to view data about the Collector or an HADevice that s/he owns.

The Collector, with role ROLE_COLLECTOR is the only role authorized to insert data i.e. create or update a resource in my REST service. Let's call this url /deviceMetrics (POST). A Collector can insert metrics for any HADevice associated with the customer. HADevices have no role and do not interact with my REST application. A Collector can only insert records to HADevices that have the same customer as the Collector.

I am using spring security 4.0 for authentication and @Secured annotation for authorization. However, I find that my code is cluttered with repetitive permission validations which take up a majority of my logic. The basic insertions and retrievals are pretty straightforward.

I want to use a PermissionEvaluator to centralize Access Control. I have to secure the following urls

- GET /collectors/{id}/deviceMetrics - I retrieve the user from the
  Principal and verify that the Collector with id={id} in my spring
  data repository belongs to the Principal and if not I send a 403
- GET/hadevices/{id}/deviceMetrics - I retrieve the user from the
  Principal and verify that the HADevice with id={id} in my spring data
  repository belongs to the Principal and if not I send a 403.
- POST /collectors/{id}/deviceMetrics - I retrieve the Collector uniqueId
  from the Principal and make sure that the Collector's id matches the
  {id} in the URL
- POST /hadevice/{id}/deviceMetrics - I retrieve the
  Collector uniqueId from the Principal and the associated Customer. I
  also pull the Customer associated with HADevice with id={id} and
  compare the two. If they are unequal, I send a 403.

My application is littered with such complex authorization requirements for each REST resource, and I want to use a custom org.springframework.security.access.PermissionEvaluator, specifically by implementing the following method.

```
boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable targetId, String targetType, Object permission)
```

I'm planning to use a combination of targetType and request.getUrl() to get a specialized Evaluator for each url and resource.
Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite broad, but I think you can get away with quite simple logic for most cases.

> GET /collectors/{id}/deviceMetrics

Given that you have a `DeviceMetrics` class with suitable properties, you can annotate your data repository with something like:

```
@PostAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or (hasRole('ROLE_USER') and returnObject.collector.owner = authentication.name)")
public DeviceMetrics getDeviceMetrics(long deviceId);
```

(This assumes that `DeviceMetrics` class has a property `collector` which has a property `owner` which is the username.)

That doesn't need a PermissionEvaluator at all. Maybe you need one for more complex cases:

> POST /collectors/{id}/deviceMetrics

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_COLLECTOR') and hasPermission(#collectorId, 'com.example.Collector', 'WRITE')")
public void saveDeviceMetrics(long collectorId, DeviceMetrics deviceMetrics);
```

You only need *one* PermissionEvaluator since you get all the information you need as method arguments.

Comment: My code ended up being littered with subtly different annotations most of which I needed to reuse. But I figured out a way to subclass the Permission object and use a HashMap<String, Permission> and select an appropriate Permission class which holds all the complex authorization logic I require.

Comment: Another pain point was that I had to write integration tests that tested authorization for each method, which takes a very long time, and any errors in SpEL only get caught during runtime.

Comment: Rob Winch in his Spring Security 3.0 presentation said he prefers PermissionEvaluators because they can be unit tested much better and also duplication of SPeL everywhere. Also, SPeL errors only show up at runtime, so I wanted to get a custom PermissionEvaluator going. Thanks for the response, because your answer made me think slightly differently and I found a solution that does not include scattering SPeL .across my code.

Comment: @horatius OK, you can cover SpEL expressions in tests though, especially version 4 of Spring Security has improved features for testing.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are wondering what my solution looks like, I borrowed from [this](http://blog.solidcraft.eu/2011/03/spring-security-by-example-securing.html) example.

It's old and it's based on xml configuration which I am not particularly fond of. But the idea is to create a Map and initialize the custom PermissionValidator and to store the authorization logic in the Permission interface implementations.

The biggest pain point was injecting an autowired HashMap of  tuples, but that's an implementation detail that reasonably experienced spring users can figure out.